# What is a virtual for an URL in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently following a tutorial on implementing a database (Mongoose) in a simple website created using Express-framework. I do not have any problem understanding the concept of models, but I fail to make sense of the lines following the comment "*Virtual for book's URL*" in the code attached. How do these lines operate, and what role does having a virtual property have in this context?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BookSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author', required: true},
    summary: {type: String, required: true},
    isbn: {type: String, required: true},
    genre: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre'}]
  }
);

// Virtual for book's URL
BookSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
  return '/catalog/book/' + this._id;
});

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Comment: `url` isn't a field in the document (it's not in the Schema) but it's a computed ("virtual") field available whenever you have a BookSchema object.  So you can call `foo.url` (assuming `foo` is a `BookSchema`) and it will generate the URL based on the `_id` of `foo`

Comment: url is a virtual property. A virtual property is a concept from "mongoose" and means that it is not actually stored in the database, (If you access the database and see the raw data it will not be there) but created logically. That means, if you do model.url you will get '/catalog/book/' plus the _id of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Virtuals are typically used for computed properties on documents.

```
BookSchema
// 'url' is the name of the virtual
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
 // you are computing dynamic url
  return '/catalog/book/' + this._id;
});
```

Important thing about virtuals is it does not store anything on database. Imagine you stored "name" and "lastname" but you want to display fullname without having "fullname" column. You would be using repeated data on database if you add `fullname` property to your schema, this will slow down and will also cost you. Instead you write virtual:

```
YourSchema.get(function(){
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
})
```

You can also go one step further and return `fullname` property as it is in a column in database. mongoose Schema takes options object

```
let options={
   toJSON:{
       virtuals: true 
   }
}
```

set the virtual

```
  let YourSchemaVirtual=YourSchema.virtual('fullname')
```

now when querying the database, get the collection

```
 YourModel.findOne({firstname:"name"}).exec(function(err,user){
    res.send(user)
 })
```

In return value you will see `fullname` field computed as `this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname` even though you have no `fullname` stored in database.